# Set automatic Fullpage.js anchors with Section ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, fullpage.js

I would like the Anchor-Array of the fullpage.js to be set automatically.
I would like to paste this into my WordPress theme, but i have problem with my functions. Do you have a idea? Thank you for help.

HTML

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section" id="page-section-1"></div> 
   <div class="section" id="page-section-2"></div>  
   <div class="section" id="page-section-3"></div>  
   <div class="section" id="page-section-4"></div>  
</div>
```

JS

```
function getAnchorarray() {
 var idarray = $("#fullpage")
     .find(".section")
     .map(function () {
         return this.id;
     }) 
     .get(); //ToArray
}

$('#fullpage').fullpage({
 navigation: false,
 scrollBar: true,
 menu: '.main-nav',
 //anchors: ["page-section-1", "page-section-2", "page-section-3", "page-section-4"],
 anchors: getAnchorarray(),
 responsiveWidth: 400
});
```

Comment: Your `getAnchorarray` function doesn't `return` anything. Just replace `var idarray = ` with `return`.

Comment: Do you have a idee for the correct code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `data-anchor` attribute :) 
As detailed [in the docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#creating-links-to-sections-or-slides):

> Note that section anchors can also be defined in the same way, by using the data-anchor attribute, if no anchors array is provided.

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide1"> Slide 1 </div>
    <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide2"> Slide 2 </div>
    <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide3"> Slide 3 </div>
    <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide4"> Slide 4 </div>
</div>
```